# VRP doubts - Tour Planning [HERE-API]

Tags: here-api

I'm having trouble getting access credentials. I need help to solve this problem, I have been giving a response to my manager about Here for a long time, but so far I have not achieved anything that would help me, my question is: How to obtain credentials? Because in the documentation, it doesn't even speak ... It just says that it has to be in compliance with OAuth Core 1.0, but it doesn't even show how to make the acquisition, just like all HERE documentation is missing information.

[Documentation Link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/dev_guide/topics/get-started/get-credentials.html)

> Note: I have already spoken to a HERE representative and still have no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were here, the option HERE is very confusing, or it can even be placed in the account using credentials or a link to learn how to make credentials, so simple, but a company already shows disorganization of a simple request, I don't even want an answer, but a question from someone else follows the link to create the credential.

[Dev Guide - New Credentials](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/content/dev_guide/)